# Why am I getting "has address 0.0.0.0" not responding for only one site

Tags: linux, networking, dns

It's been a few days since I cannot resolve `1fichier.com` on my laptop.

I don't seem to have any problem with other URLs.

```
host 1fichier.com
1fichier.com has address 0.0.0.0
1fichier.com has IPv6 address ::
1fichier.com mail is handled by 10 m.dstorage.fr.
```

When I ping it seems that my computer think that it's `localhost`.

On other computers in my local network it works perfectly fine so it doesn't seem to be a problem with my ISP modem router DNS.

```
host 1fichier.com
1fichier.com has address 5.39.224.140
1fichier.com has IPv6 address 2a00:fb40:a:1::140
1fichier.com mail is handled by 10 m.dstorage.fr.
```

I tryed to clean the dns cache with `/etc/init.d/dns-clean` restart but it doesn't change anything. My `/etc/hosts` file seems OK, my `/etc/resolv.conf` is the same as one from a computer without the problem.

I am not an expert in network stuff and I don't know what to do about this.

Has anyone an idea to solve this ?

---

```
> ping 1fichier.com
PING 1fichier.com (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.024 ms
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.084 ms
...
```

```
> traceroute 1fichier.com
traceroute to 1fichier.com (0.0.0.0), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  localhost (127.0.0.1)  0.097 ms  0.030 ms  0.025 ms
```

Comment: What happens if you ping 1fichier.com like this: `ping 1fichier.com`? What about `traceroute 1fichier.com`?

Comment: Can you try an alternate DNS server, e.g. Google or Cloudflare, e.g. `dig @8.8.8.8 1fichier.com`

Answer (score 0):

OK, well this is really a DNS problem.

I tried dig @8.8.8.8 1fichier.com like suggested and that works.

Moreover, a computer that was resolving 1fichier.com correctly yesterday doesn't anymore.

I use 1.1.1.2 as primary DNS and 8.8.8.8 as secondary since as few weeks, since I had trouble with my ISP default DNS and I found recommendation about using 1.1.1.2 on some websites.

What's weird is that the problem occurred days after the change, and changing my ISP primary DNS for 1.1.1.1 isn't working. My resolv.conf file seems to be using a local DNS server at 127.0.0.53. I didn't know about this, I guess there is some cleaning to do about it. There must be some kind of cache somewhere.

Thanks for the tip about the dig option.

Comment: Well I learned about systemd-resolve service today. Finally I changed the symbolic link of /etc/resolv.conf from /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf to /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf to go back to the old way. I also had to edit the file to manually change 1.1.1.2 with 1.1.1.1.